# redirection with angular in a sub folder

Tags: angular, .htaccess

I created a mini application with angular and I wanted to put it on my site in a sub folder.
Everything works fine, except when I refresh my page, it finds me a 404 error.
How to make sure to be redirected to the index.html of my Angular app (which is in a sub folder?)

i try with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html/projet/angular/appBookList [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had success in the path with angular in sub-folders using this .htaccess (remember to replace `SUBFOLDER` with your particular folder).

```
# Disables content negotiation (choosing the right file in ambiguous cases)
Options -Multiviews

# Enable rewriting rules
RewriteEngine on

# CASE 1: FILES 
# =============

# The next three lines define 3 options (ORed, that is, only true)
# Is a regular file, OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
# Is a symbolic link, OR
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
# Is a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# If any of the above are true, rewrite:
# ^ = start of line; .* = match any character, 0 or more times; $ = end of line
# - = no substitution
# NC = no case matching
# L = do not match any more rules
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]


# CASE 2: Subpaths (SPA)
# ======================

# ^ = start of line; () = matching group; .* = match any character, 0 or more times
# Rewrite everything to /index.html
# NC = no case matching
# L = do not match any more rules
RewriteRule ^(.*) /SUBFOLDER/index.html [NC,L]
```

Also, it is important to indicate the base of your subfolder in your index.html:

```
<base href="/SUBFOLDER/">
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly, even if I find the "reloading" a little long.
By cons I do not understand too much code, you know a good tutorial?
thank you !!

Comment: The reloading will be longer, since the entire app will be reloaded. If your caching is properly set up, it should go quicker. I don't know of a tutorial, what I have above I pieced together from the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) and the [apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code on .htacccess file I hope it's working for you.

Thanks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    # Don't rewrite files or directories
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # Rewrite everything else to index.html
    # to allow html5 state links
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```